# Azure B2C with Facebook provider

Tags: facebook, azure-ad-b2c

I try to connect my azure B2C to Facebook login. I read this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-fb-app

But I still receive this error when Azure transfer me to Facebook:

> Blocked URL: This redirection failed because the redirection URI is not allowed in the OAuth client settings of the application. Make sure OAuth client and web credentials are enabled and add all domains in your app as valid OAuth Redirect URLs.

I try to add several URI under Facebook -> Product -> Login -> Settings -> Valid OAuth Redirect URIs. I try this:

> https://b2ctenant.b2clogin.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp
>   https://login.microsoftonline.com/b2ctenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp
>   https://sitename.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/calklback
>   https://sitename.azurewebsite.net

I am out of idea...

Comment: What host are you referencing to redirect from your end-user application to your Azure AD B2C tenant? Is it `https://login.microsoftonline.com` or `https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com`?

Comment: If I go in  AzureB2C->Sing-up or sing-in policies and selecting the only policie there, my "Select Domain" is set to {tenant].b2clogin.com. It is what your asking? wierd thing, on the URL tranfered to facebook login we got that: redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2flogin.microsoftonline.com%2fte%2f{b2ctenant}.onmicrosoft.com%2foauth2%2fauthresp

Comment: Hi @Pierre-D Savard: If you're being redirected from Azure AD B2C to Facebook on the login.microsoftonline.com domain, then the redirection URL must be registered in Facebook at `https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp` (i.e. what is being sent from Azure AD B2C to Facebook). Note the `/te` path in there.

Comment: OMG! Thanks, thee /te was the error....

Comment: Hi @Christ Padgett. Can you copy your answer in a "real" answer so I can give you the credit? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following domains with Azure AD B2C:

1. your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com (recommended)
2. login.microsoftonline.com

If you're using the **your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com** domain with Azure AD B2C, then the redirection URL that is registered for Azure AD B2C in Facebook must be set to:

`https://your-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`

If you're using the **login.microsoftonline.com** domain with Azure AD B2C, then the redirection URL that is registered for Azure AD B2C in Facebook must be set to:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`

(Note the `/te` path in the redirection URL.)

Comment: What a great answer, you made my day

Comment: Based on this current doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-facebook?pivots=b2c-user-flow
They recommend to use:
 https://${your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/${your-tenant-id}/oauth2/authresp
 ... Is that basically the same as: ....
https://${your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com/${your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp

... Like are the '${your-tenant-name}.onmicrosoft.com' and '${your-tenant-id}' equivalent in that url (where the latter your-tenant-id is in this format: 12341234-1234-1243-123a-123a1324b123)?

Comment: Btw to answer my question above... I found a Microsoft url which says they are the same... someone may not want to have the word 'microsoft' in their link so they give option to use the Tenant ID as well.